# Issue regarding TCP and UDP connections in a C program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I am trying to implement a mechanism where, a client sends a coded message through UDP to the server. And on receiving this message, a TCP connection needs to be set up between the server and the client. I am facing this strange issue, where when I try to set up the TCP connection with the client, the `connect()` fails on the client side if the server received a UDP packet from the client just beforehand. If I try to set up the TCP connection with the client without any UDP messaging, then things work fine. I have attached the code from the server side and client side.

```
int sockfd, sockfd2, newsockfd, n;
char msg[1000];
sockaddr_in serverAddress, serverAddress2, clientAddress;
socklen_t len = sizeof(clientAddress);

/*create a socket*/
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

/*bind socket to an address*/
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(12330);
bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

/*-----*/
n = recvfrom(sockfd, msg, 1000, 0, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &len);
sendto(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, sizeof(clientAddress));

sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&serverAddress2,sizeof(serverAddress2));
serverAddress2.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverAddress2.sin_port = htons(12345);
bind(sockfd2, (sockaddr *)&serverAddress2, sizeof(serverAddress2));
listen(sockfd2, 10);

newsockfd = accept(sockfd2, (sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &len);
close(sockfd);
close(newsockfd);
close(sockfd2);
```

Also, none of the `bind()`, `listen()` or `socket()` functions give an error.

The client side code is as follows :-

```
/* create a UDP socket: SOCK_DGRAM */
sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
printf("enter data ");
gets(sendline);  

sendto(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

/* wait for echo */
slen = sizeof(servaddr);
n = recvfrom(sockfd, recvline, STRLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &slen);
close(sockfd);

wait(1000);
sockfd2=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);
client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
client_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
bind(sockfd2, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));

connect(sockfd2,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
```

The connect here returns `-1`.

Comment: Kind of a race condition? Client tries to connect before the server is actually ready.. What if you wait a little (say 1s) on the client before trying to connect?

Comment: @David, according to the title it's C. And the syntax is valid C code too.

Comment: @Sietse Yes I can see that. Comment was aimed at sanz who tagged it C++ for some unknown reason.

Comment: @MasoudM. I have attached the client side code too. Also, I have used a wait(1000) to prevent the race condition

Comment: @sanz Take a look at the documentation for every call you do (both on the client and server), such as bind(),connect(), accept() and so on. They can fail, and you should check every one of them for failure or success. When they do fail, execute `perror("xxx failed"); and you will learn more about why it fails (i.e you'll learn a lot more than "connect()" returned -1)

Comment: @sanz wait(1000) does not pause for 1 second, it more likely crash your application. wait() waits for a child process to end. (use sleep() or similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if `connect()` returns `-1`, check `errno` in `<errno.h>`. That should tell you why it's unhappy.

Secondly, it's probably to do with the fact that you `bind()` the client socket before connecting, which looks weird. You normally only `bind()` on the server side, to open a port for the socket. The client side of a connection is not usually bound to a port, so unless you specifically need it to be, drop the `bind()` and try again.

Comment: binding a socket should not cause a `connect` to fail, and is sometimes needed. eg, binding to a privileged port or a specific port for some protocols. (although, in this case, if both the server and client are running on the same machine, and both are binding the same port, the second bind may fail.)

Comment: @Uffe thanks a lot :) .. I removed the bind and that solved the issue

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes, you're right and that is in fact why it fails: both bind() calls refer to the port 12345 (errno should contain EADDRINUSE after the failed call). But getting rid of it althogether isn't wrong.